# Ring with additional constraints on distributivity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a ring with the exception that the distributive property 
$$a*(b+c)\neq a*b+a*c$$
doesn't always hold. However it will hold under certain additional constraints for example $b>0,c>0$. So it becomes a ring under certain circumstances.

Is there any name for and or work done on algebraic structures like that?

Answer (score 1):

Some people study variations of algebraic structures in which the operations are only partially defined (as in grupoids).

There is the notion of "partial field" for example used to construct some nontrivial matroids in combinatorics but probably your example doesn't fall in that setting (they use other structures as well such as hyperfields (algebraic structures resembling fields in which the operations are multivalued) and "fuzzy" rings).

Maybe if you restrict the operations of your structure it can become naturally a ringoid (in the sense of Sehgal for example,  [see here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093957578)). Ringoids came naturally in the context of category theory because the set of morphisms in a (small) category enriched in abelian groups (i.e, in which the morphisms can be added and commute) are of this type.

For example if you take (a skeleton of) the category of finite vector spaces you arrive at the ringoid of all matrices of all sizes together with its partial addition and partial multiplication.